# how can i get table of values exist in a TD of a table use jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

i want when i check checkbox in table  get array values check (NAME, FIRST NAME, SALAIRENET) in example below it gives me just SALAIRENET and give NaN a name for the line check, please help me.
he is my table

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="mytable">
        <tr>
            <th>Archive</th>
            <th><input type="checkbox" id="check_all"></th>
            <th>S.No.</th>
            <th>matricule</th>
            <th>nom & prenom</th>
            <th>salaire net</th>
            <th>nbre de jour </th>
            <th>prime</th>
        </tr>
        @if($salaries->count())
            @foreach($salaries as $key => $salarie)
                <tr id="tr_{{$salarie->id}}">
                  <td>archive</td>
                  <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-id="{{$salarie->id}}"></td>
                  <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $salarie->matricule }}</td>
                  <td class="name">{{ $salarie->nom }} {{ $salarie->prenom }}</td>
                  <td class="salaireValue">{{ $salarie->salairenet }}</td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="nbreJ" class="form-control" value="{{$data['nbr']}}"></td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control" value="0"></td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    </table>
```

he is my code jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#check_all').on('click', function(e) {
         if($(this).is(':checked',true))  
         {
            $(".checkbox").prop('checked', true);  
         } else {  
            $(".checkbox").prop('checked',false);  
         }  
        });
         $('.checkbox').on('click',function(){
            if($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length){
                $('#check_all').prop('checked',true);
            }else{
                $('#check_all').prop('checked',false);
            }
         });
         //get value
         $('.table').on('click', function() {
           var allChecked = $('.checkbox:checked');
           for (var i = 0; i < allChecked.length; i++) {
             var currentHtml = $(allChecked[i]).parent().siblings('.salaireValue')[0];
             var currentHtml1 = $(allChecked[i]).parent().siblings('.name')[0];
             var result = parseInt($(currentHtml)[0].innerText);
             var result1 = parseInt($(currentHtml1)[0].innerText);
             console.log(result);
             console.log(result1);
           }
         });  
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like it's not a number (NaN), given that it's class *name* and has `{{ $salarie->nom }}` - it's likely... not a number.

Comment: Given that you have "nom"(name) and "prenom"(first name?), it's unlikely either of these will be a number, so it's not clear why you're applying `parseInt` to this text - looks like you can do just: `var result1 = $(currentHtml1)[0].innerText;`

Comment: yh that  a prblm how can solve it

Comment: Please provide an example of the data that would be shown in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be helpful to create functions to break up the work. Also you can use `parseInt()` but it must receive a String that represents an Integer, so `"1000"` versus `"One Thousand"`.

Consider the following:

```js
$(function() {
  function checkToggleAll(c, v) {
    $(".checkbox", c).each(function(i, el) {
      $(el).prop("checked", v);
    });
  }

  function checkAll(c) {
    if ($(".checkbox:checked", c).length == $(".checkbox", c).length) {
      $("#check_all").prop("checked", true);
    } else {
      $("#check_all").prop("checked", false);
    }
  }

  function gatherData(c) {
    var rows = {}
    $(".checkbox:checked", c).each(function(i, el) {
      var row = $(el).parent().parent();
      rows[row.attr("id")] = {
        Name: $(".first-name", row).text().trim(),
        SurName: $(".sur-name", row).text().trim(),
        SalaireValue: parseInt($(".salaireValue", row).text().trim())
      };
    });
    return rows;
  }

  $("#check_all").change(function() {
    checkToggleAll($("tbody"), $(this).prop("checked"));
    console.log(gatherData($(".table tbody")));
  });
  $("tbody .checkbox").on("change", function() {
    checkAll($(".table tbody"));
    console.log(gatherData($(".table tbody")));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Archive</th>
      <th><input type="checkbox" id="check_all"></th>
      <th>S.No.</th>
      <th>matricule</th>
      <th>nom & prenom</th>
      <th>salaire net</th>
      <th>nbre de jour </th>
      <th>prime</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="tr_1">
      <td>archive</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-id="1"></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1001</td>
      <td class="name">Simpson, Homer</td>
      <td class="salaireValue">60000</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="nbreJ" class="form-control" value="40"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control" value="0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr_2">
      <td>archive</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-id="2"></td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>1002</td>
      <td class="name">Leonard, Lenny</td>
      <td class="salaireValue">40000</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="nbreJ" class="form-control" value="40"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control" value="0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr_3">
      <td>archive</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-id="3"></td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1002</td>
      <td class="name">Carlson, Carl</td>
      <td class="salaireValue">55000</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="nbreJ" class="form-control" value="40"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control" value="0"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I assume that the table content might get updated dynamically, so I am using `.on()` just in case. You can use `.change()` if needed.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

A few changes in your `for` loop will make it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < allChecked.length; i++) {
    var $tr = $(allChecked[i]).closest("tr");
    var item = {
        Name: $tr.find(".first-name").text(),
        SurName: $tr.find(".sur-name").text(),
        SalaireValue: $tr.find(".salaireValue").text()
    };

    console.log(item);
}
```

I've also separated the names into two spans in order to make it easy to select them.

```js
$('#check_all').on('click', function(e) {
         if($(this).is(':checked',true))  
         {
            $(".checkbox").prop('checked', true);  
         } else {  
            $(".checkbox").prop('checked',false);  
         }  
        });
         $('.checkbox').on('click',function(){
            if($('.checkbox:checked').length == $('.checkbox').length){
                $('#check_all').prop('checked',true);
            }else{
                $('#check_all').prop('checked',false);
            }
         });
         //get value
         $('.table').on('click', function() {
           var allChecked = $('.checkbox:checked');
           for (var i = 0; i < allChecked.length; i++) {
             var $tr = $(allChecked[i]).closest("tr");
             var item = {
                Name: $tr.find(".first-name").text(),
                SurName: $tr.find(".sur-name").text(),
                SalaireValue: $tr.find(".salaireValue").text()
             };
             
             console.log(item);
           }
         });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="mytable">
        <tr>
            <th>Archive</th>
            <th><input type="checkbox" id="check_all"></th>
            <th>S.No.</th>
            <th>matricule</th>
            <th>nom & prenom</th>
            <th>salaire net</th>
            <th>nbre de jour </th>
            <th>prime</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr_1">
          <td>archive</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-id="1"></td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td class="name"><span class='first-name'>Name</span> <span class='sur-name'>Surname</span></td>
          <td class="salaireValue">123</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="nbreJ" class="form-control" value="1"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control" value="0"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr_2">
          <td>archive</td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" data-id="2"></td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td class="name"><span class='first-name'>Name</span> <span class='sur-name'>Surname</span></td>
          <td class="salaireValue">456</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="nbreJ" class="form-control" value="1"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="prime" class="form-control" value="0"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```